# Unable to install react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, flux, react-bootstrap

In my flux app I try to install react-bootstrap then I got error `peerinvalid Peer react-bootstrap@0.24.3 wants react@>=0.13`.

React in my package.json is `"react": "^0.13.3"`

**Error:**
[image]

Comment: If you run `npm list` you'll see what version of React you have installed.

Comment: I will try that @limelights

Answer (score 1):

Do you tried updating your npm ?
I had a similar issue and I solved updating my npm from version 2 to version 3.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11738545)

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo: This is **an answer** - it suggests decision for the problem. Having a question in the answer doesn't automatically mean that the answer should be a comment, see e.g. [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300987/should-we-avoid-rhetorical-questions-in-answers).

Answer (score 0):

This happens a bunch, and especially when some packages are using more recent versions of React and some aren't. Check your `node_modules` folder, the package usually installs and works despite the error.